# Python - email header decoding UTF-8

Tags: python, email, email-headers

is there any Python module which helps to decode the various forms of encoded mail headers, mainly Subject, to simple - say - UTF-8 strings?

Here are example Subject headers from mail files that I have:

```
Subject: [ 201105311136 ]=?UTF-8?B?IMKnIDE2NSBBYnM=?=. 1 AO;
Subject: [ 201105161048 ] GewSt:=?UTF-8?B?IFdlZ2ZhbGwgZGVyIFZvcmzDpHVmaWdrZWl0?=
Subject: [ 201105191633 ]
  =?UTF-8?B?IERyZWltb25hdHNmcmlzdCBmw7xyIFZlcnBmbGVndW5nc21laHJhdWZ3ZW5kdW4=?=
  =?UTF-8?B?Z2VuIGVpbmVzIFNlZW1hbm5z?=
```

text - encoded sting - text

text - encoded string

text - encoded string - encoded string

Encodig could also be something else like ISO 8859-15.

Update 1: I forgot to mention, I tried email.header.decode_header

```
    for item in message.items():
    if item[0] == 'Subject':
            sub = email.header.decode_header(item[1])
            logging.debug( 'Subject is %s' %  sub )
```

This outputs

```
> DEBUG:root:Subject is [('[ 201101251025 ]
> ELStAM;=?UTF-8?B?IFZlcmbDvGd1bmcgdm9tIDIx?=. Januar 2011', None)]
```

which does not really help.

Update 2:
Thanks to Ingmar Hupp in the comments.

the first example decodes to a list of two tupels:

```
> >>> print decode_header("""[ 201105161048 ]
> GewSt:=?UTF-8?B?IFdlZ2ZhbGwgZGVyIFZvcmzDpHVmaWdrZWl0?=""")  
> [('[ 201105161048 ] GewSt:', None), (' Wegfall der Vorl\xc3\xa4ufigkeit',
> 'utf-8')]
```

is this always [(string, encoding),(string, encoding), ...] so I need a loop to concat all the [0] items to one string or how to get it all in one string?

```
> Subject: [ 201101251025 ] ELStAM;=?UTF-8?B?IFZlcmbDvGd1bmcgdm9tIDIx?=. Januar 2011
```

does not decode well:

```
> print decode_header("""[ 201101251025 ] ELStAM;=?UTF-8?B?IFZlcmbDvGd1bmcgdm9tIDIx?=. Januar 2011""")
>
>[('[ 201101251025 ] ELStAM;=?UTF-8?B?IFZlcmbDvGd1bmcgdm9tIDIx?=. Januar 2011', None)]
```

Comment: I think `make_header(decode_header(subject))` is the simplest solution. See docs for make_header(): https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.header.html#email.header.make_header

Answer (score 63):

This type of encoding is known as [MIME encoded-word](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Encoded-Word) and the [email](http://docs.python.org/library/email.html#module-email) module can decode it:

```
from email.header import decode_header
print decode_header("""=?UTF-8?B?IERyZWltb25hdHNmcmlzdCBmw7xyIFZlcnBmbGVndW5nc21laHJhdWZ3ZW5kdW4=?=""")
```

This outputs a list of tuples, containing the decoded string and the encoding used. This is because the format supports different encodings in a single header. To merge these into a single string you need to convert them into a shared encoding and then concatenate this, which can be accomplished using Python's unicode object:

```
from email.header import decode_header
dh = decode_header("""[ 201105161048 ] GewSt:=?UTF-8?B?IFdlZ2ZhbGwgZGVyIFZvcmzDpHVmaWdrZWl0?=""")
default_charset = 'ASCII'
print ''.join([ unicode(t[0], t[1] or default_charset) for t in dh ])
```

### Update 2:

The problem with this Subject line not decoding:

```
Subject: [ 201101251025 ] ELStAM;=?UTF-8?B?IFZlcmbDvGd1bmcgdm9tIDIx?=. Januar 2011
                                                                     ^
```

Is actually the senders fault, which violates the requirement of encoded-words in a header being separated by white-space, specified in [RFC 2047, section 5, paragraph 1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047#section-5): *an 'encoded-word' that appears in a header field defined as '*text' MUST be separated from any adjacent 'encoded-word' or 'text' by 'linear-white-space'.*

If need be, you can work around this by pre-processing these corrupt headers with a regex that inserts a whitespace after the encoded-word part (unless it's at the end), like so:

```
import re
header_value = re.sub(r"(=\?.*\?=)(?!$)", r"\1 ", header_value)
```

Comment: the first example decodes to a list of two tupels: `>>> print decode_header("""[ 201105161048 ] GewSt:=?UTF-8?B?IFdlZ2ZhbGwgZGVyIFZvcmzDpHVmaWdrZWl0?=""")
[('[ 201105161048 ] GewSt:', None), (' Wegfall der Vorl\xc3\xa4ufigkeit', 'utf-8')]` ist this always [(string, encoding),(string, encoding), ...] so I need a loop to concat all the [0] items to one string or how to get it all in one string?

Comment: Yes, but you need to take into account that they are (or can be) using different encodings, so a bit of conversion is required. Updated answer with example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The wrong encoding ofd encoded-word is really odd, because the mail header was created by perl MIME::Lite.

Comment: The update2 will broken for such subject =?utf-8?Q?=E5=9B=9E=E5=A4=8D=EF=BC=9A_=E6=94=B6=E4=BB=B6=E7=AE=B1=5F03?=

Comment: I think you should use `' '.join` instead of `''.join` to add the spacing between the words.

Comment: The python email library looks like a low level library to me. A bit like assembler ... I would like to avoid it, but don't know a better solution :-( -- don't get me wrong: Thank you for sharing your knowledge, it helped me to get things done faster.

Comment: @guettli: On Python 3, [`str(make_header(decode_header(subject)))`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21715870/4279) works for all examples from the question (no need for `re.sub`, `''.join`) (it is 3 calls instead of 1 but it is not that bad).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian unfortunately I will still need to support Python 2.7

Answer (score 62):

I was just testing with encoded headers in Python 3.3, and I found that this is a very convenient way to deal with them:

```
>>> from email.header import Header, decode_header, make_header

>>> subject = '[ 201105161048 ] GewSt:=?UTF-8?B?IFdlZ2ZhbGwgZGVyIFZvcmzDpHVmaWdrZWl0?='
>>> h = make_header(decode_header(subject))
>>> str(h)
'[ 201105161048 ] GewSt:  Wegfall der Vorläufigkeit'
```

As you can see it automatically adds whitespace around the encoded words.

It internally keeps the encoded and ASCII header parts separate as you can see when it re-encodes the non-ASCII parts:

```
>>> h.encode()
'[ 201105161048 ] GewSt: =?utf-8?q?_Wegfall_der_Vorl=C3=A4ufigkeit?='
```

If you want the whole header re-encoded you could convert the header to a string and then back into a header:

```
>>> h2 = Header(str(h))
>>> str(h2)
'[ 201105161048 ] GewSt:  Wegfall der Vorläufigkeit'
>>> h2.encode()
'=?utf-8?q?=5B_201105161048_=5D_GewSt=3A__Wegfall_der_Vorl=C3=A4ufigkeit?='
```

Comment: This is the right answer, the documentation in [`email.header`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/email.header.html) doesn't make this clear, but `make_header(decode_header())` is how to properly decode email headers.

Comment: This technique appears to work for Python 2.7, too, but using `unicode()` instead of `str()` to convert the header object back to a (unicode) string.

Comment: Thank you! Saved me 30 minutes of wondering through the official docs. :)

Answer (score 6):

```
def decode_header(value):
    return ' '.join((item[0].decode(item[1] or 'utf-8').encode('utf-8') for item in email.header.decode_header(value)))
```

Answer (score 5):

How about decoding headers in the following way:

```
import poplib, email

from email.header import decode_header, make_header

...

        subject, encoding = decode_header(message.get('subject'))[0]

        if encoding==None:
            print "\n%s (%s)\n"%(subject, encoding)
        else:
            print "\n%s (%s)\n"%(subject.decode(encoding), encoding)
```

this gets subject from email and decodes it with specified encoding (or no decoding if encoding set to None).

Worked for me for encodings set as 'None', 'utf-8', 'koi8-r', 'cp1251', 'windows-1251'

Comment: why the [0] ? decode_header return two arguments, you want to put both in subject and encoding respectively, but [0] seems that you want to take just first argument

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue, but my case was a little bit different:

- Python 3.5 (The question is from 2011, but still very high on google)
- Read message directly from file as byte-string

Now the cool feature of the python 3 email.parser is that all headers are automatically decoded to Unicode-Strings. However this causes a little "misfortune" when dealing with wrong headers. So following header caused the problem:

```
Subject: Re: =?ISO-2022-JP?B?GyRCIVYlMyUiMnE1RCFXGyhC?=
 (1/9(=?ISO-2022-JP?B?GyRCNmIbKEI=?=) 6:00pm-7:00pm) 
 =?ISO-2022-JP?B?GyRCJE4kKkNOJGkkOxsoQg==?=
```

This resulted in the following `msg['subject']`:

```
Re: 「コア会議」 (1/9(=?ISO-2022-JP?B?GyRCNmIbKEI=?=) 6:00pm-7:00pm)  のお知らせ
```

Well the issue is uncompliance with RFC 2047 (There should be a line-white-space after the MIME encoded word) as already described in the [answer by Ingmar Hupp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7331577/2003325). So my answer is inspired by his.

**Solution 1:** Fix byte-string before actually parsing the email. This seemed to be the better solution, however I was struggling to implement a Regex substitution on byte-strings. So I opted for solution 2:

**Solution 2:** Fix the already parsed and partly-decoded header value:

```
with open(file, 'rb') as fp:  # read as byte-string
    msg = email.message_from_binary_file(fp, policy=policy.default)
    subject_fixed = fix_wrong_encoded_words_header(msg['subject'])


def fix_wrong_encoded_words_header(header_value):
    fixed_header_value = re.sub(r"(=\?.*\?=)(?=\S)", r"\1 ", header_value)

    if fixed_header_value == header_value:  # nothing needed to fix
        return header_value
    else:
        dh = decode_header(fixed_header_value) 
        default_charset = 'unicode-escape'
        correct_header_value = ''.join([str(t[0], t[1] or default_charset) for t in dh])
        return correct_header_value
```

**Explanation of important parts:**

I modified the regex of Ingmar Hupp to only replace wrong MIME encoded words: `(=\?.*\?=)(?=\S)` [Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/P3L6LQa-pogvywo9). Because doing for all would heavily slow dow the parsing (Parsing about 150'000 mails).

After applying the `decode_header` function to the `fixed_header`, we have following parts in `dh`:

```
dh == [(b'Re: \\u300c\\u30b3\\u30a2\\u4f1a\\u8b70\\u300d (1/9(', None), 
       (b'\x1b$B6b\x1b(B', 'iso-2022-jp'), 
       (b' ) 6:00pm-7:00pm)  \\u306e\\u304a\\u77e5\\u3089\\u305b', None)]
```

To re-decode the unicode-escaped sequences, we set `default_charset = 'unicode-escape'` when building the new header-value.

The `correct_header_value` is now:

```
Re: 「コア会議」 (1/9(金 ) 6:00pm-7:00pm)  のお知らせ'
```

I hope this will save somebody some time.

Addition: The [answer by Sander Steffann](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21715870/2003325) didn't really help me, because I wasn't able to get the raw-value of the header-field out of the message-class.

Answer (score 2):

This script works fine for me.. I use this script to decode all email subjects

```
pat2=re.compile(r'(([^=]*)=\?([^\?]*)\?([BbQq])\?([^\?]*)\?=([^=]*))',re.IGNORECASE)

def decodev2(a):
    data=pat2.findall(a)
    line=[]
    if data:
            for g in data:
                    (raw,extra1,encoding,method,string,extra)=g
                    extra1=extra1.replace('\r','').replace('\n','').strip()
                    if len(extra1)>0:
                            line.append(extra1)
                    if method.lower()=='q':
                            string=quopri.decodestring(string)
                            string=string.replace("_"," ").strip()
                    if method.lower()=='b':
                            string=base64.b64decode(string)
                    line.append(string.decode(encoding,errors='ignore'))
                    extra=extra.replace('\r','').replace('\n','').strip()
                    if len(extra)>0:
                            line.append(extra)
            return "".join(line)
    else:
            return a
```

samples:

```
=?iso-8859-1?q?una-al-dia_=2806/04/2017=29_Google_soluciona_102_vulnerabi?=
 =?iso-8859-1?q?lidades_en_Android?=

=?UTF-8?Q?Al=C3=A9grate?= : =?UTF-8?Q?=20La=20compra=20de=20tu=20vehi?= =?UTF-8?Q?culo=20en=20tan=20s=C3=B3lo=2024h?= =?UTF-8?Q?=2E=2E=2E=20=C2=A1Valoraci=C3=B3n=20=26?= =?UTF-8?Q?ago=20=C2=A0inmediato=21?=
```

Comment: This works fine for some emails, but for instance `=?utf-8?Q?1=20underlig=20opfindelse=20til=20at=20forbr=C3=A6nde=20din=20v=C3=A6gt=20hurtigt=20og=20nemt=20...?=` is decoded to `b'1 underlig opfindelse til at forbr\xc3\xa6nde din v\xc3\xa6gt hurtigt og nemt ...'` and not `1 underlig opfindelse til at forbrænde din vægt hurtigt og nemt ...`

Answer (score 2):

```
from email.header import decode_header
mail = email.message_from_bytes(data[0][1])

subject_list = decode_header(mail['subject'])

sub_list = []
for subject in subject_list:
    if subject[1]:
        subject = (subject[0].decode(subject[1]))
    elif type(subject[0]) == bytes:
        subject = subject[0].decode('utf-8')
    else:
        subject = subject[0]
    sub_list.append(subject)

subject = ''.join(sub_list)
print('Subject:' + subject)
```

Comment: Does your code means that an email can have more than one subjects?

Answer (score -1):

Python has an e-mail lib.
http://docs.python.org/library/email.header.html

Take a look at email.header.decode_header()

Answer (score -1):

for me this worked perfect (and *always* gives me a string):

```
dmsgsubject, dmsgsubjectencoding = email.header.decode_header(msg['Subject'])[0]
msgsubject = dmsgsubject.decode(*([dmsgsubjectencoding] if dmsgsubjectencoding else [])) if isinstance(dmsgsubject, bytes) else dmsgsubject
```