# decode utf8 mail header

Tags: python, email, utf-8

In my MUA (Thunderbird 15.0.1) both mail subjects are displayed like this:

```
Keine Mail zu "Abschlagsänderung" gefunden
```

Here is a snippet to reproduce it:

```
import email

for subject in ['Subject: Re: Keine Mail zu "=?utf-8?q?Abschlags=C3=A4nderung?=" gefunden',
                'Subject: =?utf-8?q?Keine_Mail_zu_=22Abschlags=C3=A4nderung=22_gefunden?=']:
    msg=email.message_from_string(subject)
    print email.Header.decode_header(msg.get('subject'))
```

Output:

```
[('Re: Keine Mail zu "=?utf-8?q?Abschlags=C3=A4nderung?=" gefunden', None)]
[('Keine Mail zu "Abschlags\xc3\xa4nderung" gefunden', 'utf-8')]
```

The first header can't be parsed by python, but thunderbird does. It was created by KMail/1.11.4

How can I parse the first header with umlauts in Python 2.7?

Comment: Related: [email header decoding UTF-8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331351/python-email-header-decoding-utf-8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [RFC 2047](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047),

> An 'encoded-word' MUST NOT appear within a 'quoted-string'.

A 'quoted-string' according to [RFC 822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822) is

> quoted-string = <"> *(qtext/quoted-pair) <">; Regular qtext or quoted chars.

So I think the Python library is right, as

```
"=?utf-8?q?Abschlags=C3=A4nderung?="
```

is a quoted string. A better alternative with minimal quoting would be

```
=?utf-8?q?=22Abschlags=C3=A4nderung=22?=
```

having the `"` encoded as `=22`.

You could parse them by replacing the `"` with `=?utf-8?q?=22?=`:

```
>>> email.Header.decode_header('=?utf-8?q?=22?= =?utf-8?q?Abschlags=C3=A4nderung?= =?utf-8?q?=22?=')
[('"Abschlags\xc3\xa4nderung"', 'utf-8')]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. Since it is a bug in KMail, and this MUA is not very wide spread, I will leave my code like it is.

Comment: I came across this bug in KMail again. The bug in KMail is still open and several years old: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=69007