# How do I get unfolded email headers in Python3?

Tags: python, email, python-3.x

(*Note: this question has nothing to do with encoding, as should be clear by reading it.  Ignore the suggestion above.*)

I'm learning Python and figured a nice tool to start out with would be something that would grab some emails over MIME and display a given header.  The following is basically my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from imaplib import IMAP4_SSL
from netrc import netrc
from email import message_from_bytes

conn = IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
auth = netrc().hosts['imap.gmail.com']

conn.login(auth[0], auth[2])
conn.select()

typ, data = conn.search(None, 'ALL')
i = 0
for num in reversed(data[0].split()):
    i += 1
    typ, data = conn.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
    email = message_from_bytes(data[0][1])
    print("%i: %s" % (int(num), email.get('subject')))
    if i == 5:
        break
conn.close()
conn.logout()
```

The frustrating thing is that the header comes back folded; thus showing through
the underlying email string instead of the actual value inside of the header.

How can I get the correctly unfolded header value?  I'd like
to stick with core python3 stuff but I'm open to external deps if I must.

Comment: There is a [provided method to decode the header](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/email.header.html#email.header.decode_header).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - email header decoding UTF-8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331351/python-email-header-decoding-utf-8)

Comment: No, this is not about UTF-8

Comment: did you read the top answer that shows using `from email.header import decode_header` ? Which I also linked to above? It will decode from any MIME type specified.

Comment: Yes, and I tried it.  As I said, this is not about UTF-8 or character encoding.  using that function makes exactly no difference.

Comment: Out of curiousity, what exactly is Your output, what do You mean by folded? I'm getting header in plain text.

Comment: A folded header is one with a newline in it.  Most emails do not have folded subjects but it looks to me like most github issues do.

Comment: With python, some header lines get wrapped between msg=email.message_from_file() and msg.as_string().  With python3 the same message comes back intact.  (This is Python 2.7.16 vs. Python 3.7.3).

Answer (score 2):

Use [Policy Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.policy.html#module-email.policy) to enable unfolding in the Python email package. In your script, you would have to add:

```
from email.policy import SMTPUTF8
```

to import the policy *SMTPUTF8*, and later use that when calling *message_from_bytes*:

```
email = message_from_bytes(data[0][1], policy=SMTPUTF8)
```

I tried your script with Python 3.9.5, actually all policies except *compat32* (which is used when the parameter *policy* is absent) enabled unfolding.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: strip newlines

I'd love it if there were a simple answer to this, so if you have a better one feel free to add it.  In the meantime, this sorta ghetto solution works perfectly:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from imaplib import IMAP4_SSL
from netrc import netrc
from email import message_from_bytes
import re

conn = IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
auth = netrc().hosts['imap.gmail.com']

conn.login(auth[0], auth[2])
conn.select()

typ, data = conn.search(None, 'ALL')
i = 0
for num in reversed(data[0].split()):
    i += 1
    typ, data = conn.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
    email = message_from_bytes(data[0][1])
    raw_header = email.get('subject')
    header = re.sub('[\r\n]', '', header)

    print("%i: %s" % (int(num), header))
    if i == 5:
        break
conn.close()
conn.logout()
```

Comment: If that's just it it (might be faster - that's just bold untested statement) to avoid regex and use python builtin `header = header.replace("\r\n", "")`...well, ok ran some tests. It's about 10 times faster in my case.

Comment: It could be either \r\n or just \n.  I'm not super worried about performance here.