# Python: What is this encoding and how to decode?

Tags: python-3.x, encoding, character-encoding

I have a lot of strings from mail bodies, that print as such:

```
=C3=A9
```

This should be 'é' for example.

What exactly is this encoding and how to decode it?

I'm using python 3.5

EDIT:

I managed to get the body of the mail properly encoded by applying:

```
quopri.decodestring(sometext).decode('utf-8')
```

However I still struggle to get the FROM , TO, SUBJECT, etc... parts get right.

This is how I construct the e-mails:

```
import imaplib
import email
import quopri


mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
mail.login('mail@gmail.com', '*******')
mail.list()

mail.select('"[Gmail]/All Mail"') 



typ, data = mail.search(None, 'SUBJECT', '"{}"'.format('123456'))

data[0].split()

print(data[0].split())

for e_mail in data[0].split():
    typ, data = mail.fetch('{}'.format(e_mail.decode()),'(RFC822)')
    raw_mail = data[0][1]
    email_message = email.message_from_bytes(raw_mail)
    if email_message.is_multipart():
        for part in email_message.walk():
            if part.get_content_type() == 'text/plain':
                if part.get_content_type() == 'text/plain':
                    body = part.get_payload()
                    to = email_message['To']

                    utf = quopri.decodestring(to)

                    text = utf.decode('utf-8')
                    print(text)
.
.
.
```

I still got this: =?UTF-8?B?UMOpdGVyIFBldMWRY3o=?=

Comment: Try for ex. `'é'.encode().decode("utf-8")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solved it:

```
from email.header import decode_header
def mail_header_decoder(self,header):
        if header != None:
            mail_header_decoded = decode_header(header)
            l=[]  
            header_new=[]
            for header_part in mail_header_decoded: 
                l.append(header_part[1])

            if all(item == None for item in l):
                # print(header)
                return header
            else:
                for header_part in mail_header_decoded:
                    header_new.append(header_part[0].decode())
                header_new = ''.join(header_new) # convert list to string
                # print(header_new)
                return header_new
```

Answer (score 3):

That's called "quoted-printable" encoding.  It's defined by RFC 1521.  Its purpose is to replace unusual character values by a sequence of normal, safe characters so that the message can be handled safely by the email system.

In fact there are two levels of encoding here.  First the letter `'é'` was encoded into UTF-8 which produces `'\xc3\xa9'`, and then that UTF-8 was encoded into the quoted-printable form `'=C3=A9'`

You can undo the quoted-printable step by using the `decode` or `decodestring` method of the `quopri` module, documented at https://docs.python.org/3/library/quopri.html  That will look something like:

```
    import quopri

    source = '=C3=A9'
    print(quopri.decodestring(source))
```

That will undo the quoted-printable encoding and show you the UTF-8 bytes `'\xc3\xa9'`.  To get back to the letter `'é'` you need to use the `decode` string method and tell Python that those bytes contain a UTF-8 encoding, something like:

```
    utf = quopri.decodestring(source)
    text = utf.decode('utf-8')
    print(text)
```

UTF-8 is only one of many possible ways of encoding letters into bytes.  For example, if your `'é'` had been encoded as ISO-8859-1 it would have had the byte value `'\xe9'` and its quoted-printable representation would have been `'=E9'`.

When you're dealing with email, you should see a **Content-Type** header that tells you what type of content is being sent and which letter-to-bytes encoding was applied to the text of the message (or to an individual MIME part, in a multipart message).  If that text was then encoded again by applying the quoted-printable encoding, that additional step should be indicated by a **Content-Transfer-Encoding** header.  So your message with UTF-8 encoded text carried in quoted-printable format should have had headers that look like this:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

Comment: Thank you ottomeister, you helped a lot. However I got stuck again. I added my question in the description above. I would appreciate any help a lot!!!

Comment: The format used in email headers is called a "MIME encoded-word".  It is defined by RFC 2047.  The answers to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331351/python-email-header-decoding-utf-8 explain how to use the Python `email.header` module to decode that kind of header.

Comment: Thank you again. I found out yesterday and wrote a little function to decode header items.